# Do the arguments of a function defined within a function create an error when they are the same as the enclosing function's arguments?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function:

```
function hi(message) {
    return message;
}
```

And I have a function within that function:

```
function hi(message) {
    function say(message) {
        return message;
    }
    say("hello");
}
hi("sup");
```

Do the arguments mess with each other if they are the same?

Answer (score 3):

The inner functions arguments will hide the outer ones.

There won't be any errors.

Comment: Well, there won't be any errors until the overshadowing confuses somebody, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

No.

```
// let this be message #1
function hi(message) {
    //Inside this scope we have message === #1

    // let this be message #2
    function say(message) {
        // inside this scope we have message === #2
        return message;
    }
    say("hello");
}    
hi("sup");
```

It will work as expected.

From a readability / maintainance point of view I think it's bad to re use parameter / variable names.

You also have the problem that in the inner function your `#2` variable is shadowing variable `#1`

This means its impossible to access `#1` inside `say`